# ArCore success floor find

Tags: java, android, kotlin, arcore

Is there a method, which is performed after a floor is found in ArCore? I tried to look for a solution, but I did not have success. I am looking for something like .
I need to diplay fbx, exactly when surface is detected .
edit: i will be thankful also for condition, which i can checkt that with.

> onSurfaceDetection()

Answer (score 1):

There is a sample of that in [Solar System ARCore Sample](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/solarsystem/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/samples/solarsystem/SolarActivity.java) from Google.

```
arSceneView
    .getScene()
    .addOnUpdateListener(
        frameTime -> {
          for (Plane plane : frame.getUpdatedTrackables(Plane.class)) {
            if (plane.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING) {
              // Plane detected
            }
          }
        });
```